# How do I obtain the user device log for the app once it is in production?

Tags: android, error-logging

I am using Firebase for this purpose as of now . But i get storage exceeded problem.
I have put logs at certain places , as i want to track what went wrong if some abnormal behavior is reported.
Is there some other possible way to get device logs once the app is in production for crashes and abnormal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Bugfender](https://bugfender.com/) with limited success in the past. It gives you access to one day old logs for free but for more then that you will have to pay.

Comment: wont it eat up too much battery and data if we send each logger to bugfeneder.Is there some mechanism we write to our local file and then upload to bugfender.

Comment: They handle that themselves. I did profile my battery usage at that time and there was no notable difference. And no, I don't think it is possible to upload a log file to bugfender.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [crashlytics](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/overview.html) to your app. Once it's configured, it shows all the crash logs of all the versions in the production. 
Please note: This only works for news versions of the app for hich Crashlytics is installed.

If you have configured Firebase Crash reporting then you can see the logs in [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1).

Please also note Firebase crash reporting and Crashlytics are one and the same as Google purchased Crashlytics from Twiter as part of Fabric platform

[image]

Comment: I am not looking for crash library,looking for some remote logging mechanism